# PHP - Adding a div tag after a certain amount of results in a foreach loop

Tags: php

I have a bit of a weird issue.

I want to add a div tag around remaining results after a certain amount is reached in my foreach loop.

So, after the loop returns 6 results, it wraps the rest in

The code i have to return results at the moment is:

```
foreach ($fpbanners as $banners):
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />
endforeach;
```

At the end i need to source code to look something like the following so all results after the 6th is wrapped in the div tag

```
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />
<img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />
<div class="test">
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />
</div>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are going to want to use the [`modulus`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) operator: [wiki link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operator)

```
$i=0;
<div class="test">
foreach ($fpbanners as $banners):
    if ($i % 6 == 0) :
         </div><div class="test">
    endif;
    <img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />
    $i++;
endforeach;
</div>
```

Untested, but some tinkering should get you what you want.

If you do not want it to repeat on every 6th result, then you just want the `==` and not the `modulus` operator (`%`).

---

**UPDATE**

While loop example:

```
$i=0;
$max = count($fpbanners);
echo '<div class="test">'; 
while ($i < $max) {
     if ($i % 6 == 0) {
          echo '</div><div class="test">';
     }

     echo '<img src="' . $fpbanners[$i] . '" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />';
     $i++;
}
```

Not knowing how your array is structured etc, that is the best I can do for you, a rough example.

Comment: Is there a way to do the same thing in a while loop?

Comment: Beautiful ... Works fantastic .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use either a counter

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($fpbanners as $banners) {
    $i++

    if ($i > 6) {
        print('<div class="test">');
    }

    print('<img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />');
}

if ($i > 6) {
    print('</div>');
}
```

Or if the array contains nice numeric keys (read 0, 1, 2, 3, etc)

```
foreach ($fpbanners as $index=>$banners) {
    if ($index > 5) {
        print('<div class="test">');
    }

    print('<img src="image.jpg" alt="image description" width="773" height="432" />');
}

if ($index > 5) {
    print('</div>');
}
```